# Why JSON strings transform with bash shell

Tags: json, bash, shell

I have this:

```
$ export foo=["foo","zoom"]
$ echo $foo
[foo,zoom]
$ export foo='["foo","zoom"]'
$ echo $foo
["foo","zoom"]
```

why is it that the " (double quote) chars get removed if I don't wrap in single quotes?

Comment: Single quotes prevent bash substitution and everything inside them is kept verbatim; if you don't use them, the source gets parsed and the quotes dropped.

Comment: thanks @linuxfan this is the exact problem that I have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790238/properly-escape-json-for-use-with-bash

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
$ echo "foo"
foo
```

We notice that there aren't any quotes in that string. From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes):

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal
>   value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’,
>   ‘`’, ‘\’,

So double quotes are bash syntax. To get literal double quotes we need to escape them:

```
$ echo \"foo\"
"foo"
```

Another option to escaping is to use single quotes (again from the bash manual):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal
>   value of each character within the quotes.

So this is equivalent to the above command:

```
$ echo '"foo"'
"foo"
```

Applied to your specific example, we can see this:

```
$ export foo=["foo","zoom"]
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo="[foo,zoom]"
```

The double quotes are parsed away.

But with

```
$ export foo='["foo","zoom"]'
$ declare -p foo
declare -x foo="[\"foo\",\"zoom\"]"
```

The single quotes have the same effect as escaping the double quotes.