# Properly escape JSON for use with bash

Tags: json, bash, shell

I have this node.js script:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const json = JSON.stringify(['foo','bar']);

const k = cp.spawn('bash');

const cmd = `
  export foo=${json}
`;

k.stdin.end(`
    ${cmd}
    echo "foo is: $foo"; exit 0;
`);


k.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
k.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

I get this output to stdout:

```
foo is: '[foo,bar]'
```

and am trying to get this instead:

```
foo is: ["foo","bar"]
```

it looks like this phenomena is what's happening, but I can't figure out why:

[Why JSON strings transform with bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790047/why-json-strings-transform-with-bash-shell?noredirect=1#comment94431552_53790047)

does anyone know what's happening in my script and how to get the JSON string to remain JSON as it travels through bash?

Comment: On my computer I don't get the single quotes around the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want bash to keep a string unchanged, you need to use [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes).

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal
>   value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not
>   occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

This code generates the desired output:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const json = JSON.stringify(['foo','bar']);

const k = cp.spawn('bash');

// NOTE single quotes around '${json}':
const cmd = `
  export foo='${json}' 
`;

k.stdin.end(`
    ${cmd}
    echo "foo is: $foo"; exit 0;
`);


k.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
k.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put single quotes around the JSON.

```
const cmd = `
  export foo='${json}'
`;
```

But if there are any single quotes in the JSON they need to be outside of the quotes that delimit the JSON, and inside a set of double quotes instead. So you should first do:

```
json = json.replace(/'/g, "'\"'\"'");
```